# Maven enforcer plugin crashing because of version string in open JDK

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I downloaded open jdk and having some issues with maven build, specifically, maven-enforcer-plugin. Using plugin version 1.4.1.

Enforcer plugin is trying to enforce JDK version like

```
<requireJavaVersion>
    <version>[13,)</version>
    <message>[ERROR] OLD JDK [${java.version}] in use. Need JDK 13.0 or newer</message>
</requireJavaVersion>
```

Enforcer plugin crashes with following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2
    at java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd (String.java:3319)
    at java.lang.String.substring (String.java:1874)
    at org.apache.commons.lang.SystemUtils.getJavaVersionAsFloat (SystemUtils.java:1122)
    at org.apache.commons.lang.SystemUtils.<clinit> (SystemUtils.java:818)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequireJavaVersion.execute (RequireJavaVersion.java:52)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.EnforceMojo.execute (EnforceMojo.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
```

After spending lot of time, I finally figured out JDK is reporting version which does not have decimal point. This is causing the plugin to fail.

```
java -version
   openjdk version "13" 2019-09-17
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13+33)
   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13+33, mixed mode, sharing)
```

What will be the workaround in this situation?

Comment: Is this still the case for maven-enforcer-plugin 3.0.0-M3 ?

Comment: @JFMeier, yes, faced same issue

Comment: This is related to new way of providing JVM’s version: http://www.owsiak.org/java-9-10-and-macos-issues-with-java-version/

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [recent sources](https://github.com/apache/maven-enforcer/blob/master/enforcer-rules/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/enforcer/RequireJavaVersion.java) it is still using commons-lang to detect the Java version. This implementation has some issues and is not forward compatible. I've created [MENFORCER-347](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MENFORCER-347), which should be an easy fix. I've marked it as up-for-grabs, so it'll show up in the list of https://s.apache.org/up-for-grabs_maven and hopefully somebody will pick it up.